# Surprisingly I can't use back camera in android using OpenCV in Galaxy S4

Tags: android, opencv, galaxy

I've developed an android application using opencv and I used back camera in my app. I can use my app in Galaxy S1 but surprisingly when I want to test it on Galaxy s4, after some seconds my phone restarts!
How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

you can look at this question that I post:

http://answers.opencv.org/question/20054/video-get-stuck-on-galaxy-s4/

I have also the same problem, till now I didn't solve this problem.

you can see here the status of the bug: http://code.opencv.org/issues/3113 .

I use MediaMetadataRetriever that is much slower and you have to save the video first.